# Sitecore 8.2 Azure Web App / Solr VMs

Tags: solr, azure

We are running Sitecore 8.2 as a WebApp on Azure, with this we using Solr on VMs , using along with Zookeeper [3 nodes].

There is odd behavior we are seeing, if we make any configurations on Solr as restart it, we need to also restart the Azure Webapp before Sitecore starts to work again.

Is this expected behavior as we are not sure whats going on.

Thanks
S